# what would be the way to save fields of a form before creating a record

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, lightning-web-components, community

I am working with a form with simple fields, which I want to have an automatic save, that is, if I close the tab the data remains there until I create the record.
Is there a way? I have used the localstorage but not if it is good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage but yes that is not a right solution. I would suggest to create a **status picklist field** and keep the status as **Draft** till you want to create the record. In real, you will be creating the record but you will use status draft to identify the record you want to show next time users open the same form.